# Taking a filename as an input while running a program I compiled in cpp

Tags: c++, input, g++

In cpp, I need to run a program like this

```
g++ *.cpp -o out

./out <input.txt> <somenumber>
```

where input.txt is a text file containing lines of information I need to proccess, and somenumber is an integer value I need to use.

I am searching for hours and couldn't find the answer I was looking for,

I found solutions that work like

```
./out < input.txt
```

reads the input.txt line as a string which then in the code I can process,
but the assignment says that the code will be run only and specifically as

```
./out <input.txt> <somenumber>
```

can anyone help ?

I have wrote some code, in which I wrote my main as

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[] ){
```

but when I run

```
./out <input.txt>
```

the terminal gives an error saying

```
" -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline' "
```

edit: typo

Comment: Your attempt with the `int main(int argc, char* argv[])` should work correctly. Could you supply the exact code and command you tried to execute? This error doesn't seem correct here

Comment: On my linux, I would run (without quotes)  "./out  input.txt" ... the less-than and greater than ('<' and '>') are i/o stream redirection on bash.  Do you know what shell you are using?  Try (without quotes) "echo $0"  (that is a 'dollar-zero')

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in wanting to accomplish this using argc and argv. Something like this should work

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  std::string file_name;
  std::string number;
  if(argc == 3) {
    file_name = argv[1];
    number = argv[2];
  }

  std::cout << "Filename: " << file_name << " number: " << number << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By convention, the use of **< >** to enclose an input parameter signifies that the parameter is mandatory for the command.

Therefore, the command

```
./out <input.txt> <some_number>
```

signifies that the two parameters - **input.txt** and **some_number** are mandatory.

**The command can be run as:**

```
./out input.txt 101
```

**Here is an example of working code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  string inputFile;
  string someNumber;

  if(argc != 3) {
      cout << "Sorry! Wrong input \n";
      cout << "Usage: ./out <input_file_name> <some_number> \n";
      return -1;
  }

  inputFile = argv[1];
  someNumber = argv[2];

  cout << "Processing ...\n";
  cout << "File = " << inputFile << ", Number = " << someNumber << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
$ ./out input.txt 101

Processing ...
File = input.txt, Number = 101
```

Comment: Oh, I see now. Thanks a lot. I had my suspicions but wasn't sure, you really saved my life. Thanks